# My refactored React code does NOT work - Why?

Tags: reactjs, function, class, refactoring, react-context

I wanted to refactor my class based context provider to a function - but the refactored code does NOT work. I do not understand why. Can someone give me a hint how to fix the code ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the code in the function `ThemeContextProvider` from:

```
setTheme(prevState => (prevState.theme === 'Day' ? 'Night' : 'Day'));
```

to

```
setTheme(theme => (theme === 'Day' ? 'Night' : 'Day'));
```

This fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The argument to the setTheme should be a value. Do this instead:

```
 const toggleTheme = () => {
    setTheme(theme === "Day" ? "Night" : "Day");
  };
```

Comment: Thanks @EVeras . . . the code also works with a function